# Looking for an obscured amplifier

Tags: identification, datasheet

I got this amplifier for a (glas)fiber switch.
My guess is that this is originally an audio amplifier.
Unfortunately the company that made the PCB obscured the part with a laser engraver.
I only removed the name of the company from the pictures.

Does anyone know this part?

The reason why i want to know the part better is that i can improve the parameter to fit the switch or replace it with an other suitable one

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an audio amplifier it might be the [TDA1516BQ](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/TDA1516BQ-843523.pdf): -

[image]

Image taken from [gleeBay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/395125198565?chn=ps&_ul=GB&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1fL3dQxkTTQyN31pcuXM7qw93&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=395125198565&targetid=1647205089720&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9046470&poi=&campaignid=19926849521&mkgroupid=147378848803&rlsatarget=pla-1647205089720&abcId=9311021&merchantid=5309806263&gclid=CjwKCAiAibeuBhAAEiwAiXBoJHxchjEMYhHDAGtzdrznR6VJVLLvAggrv0iydioCMEUmmMjKIxo-PRoCM-UQAvD_BwE)

A lot of audio amplifiers begin with the letters TDA so it's worth searching for any that don't have a protruding heatsink, have decent sized mounting slots and, have 13 electrical pins arranged down the bottom edge.

I advise you to check the pin functions and see if they align with sensible components on the PCB. Also check power supply rails are correct too.